# PHP <5.4 LDAP 1000 rows limit

Tags: php, ldap, limit

I get :

```
Warning: ldap_search(): Partial search results returned: Sizelimit exceeded
```

When trying to use `ldap_search` on `>1000` records.

Found solution for `>5.4`, but still can't find for < 5.4 PHP Version.

P.S. can't update server version. Also tried to set limit:

```
ldap_set_option($ldap_connect, LDAP_OPT_SIZELIMIT, 100);
```

but it brings same warning.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24913366/php-ldap-overcoming-size-limit

Comment: In my case it's not full solution,because of AD server settings, but setting $sizelimit parameter to 0 and applying filters e.g. by letters solves the problem. E.g. getting all records by "a", "b", "c" at each search ant putting them to one array.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be out of luck!

You can alter the sizelimit of your *client* to any value you like, but you can not set the sizelimit of the *server*. That is only possible for the Admin of the LDAP-Server and they usually have a good reason to limit the result-set that is returned. That server-sided limit usually is 1000 entries. By setting `ldap_set_option($ldap_connect, LDAP_OPT_SIZELIMIT, 100);` you can reduce that limit to 100 entries being returned but you can not extend it beyond the server-limit.

The only way to get "more" results back is to use [paged results](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-control-paged-result.php). That means you query the LDAP-Server multiple times, each time getting the maximum result-set but each time starting with the first entry you didn't yet recieve. In your PHP-Code you can then aggregate the results to finally have more than 1000 entries.

But that is only available since PHP 5.4. So it seems you are out of luck.

In my eyes there are three solutions:

1. Patch the LDAP-Extension and compile it so that your PHP-Version can use the paged-results,
2. Update to a [supported PHP-Version](http://php.net/supported-versions.php) or
3. Convince your LDAP-Admin to raise the server-sided sizelimit.

As 3 is usually very hard and 1 takes a lot of time I strongly encourage you to consider option 2!

Comment: And 4.use LDAP filters to get filtered records and then join them to 1 array. I've used `(&(cn='*')(samaccountname=.$firstLetter."*"))` in alphabet foreach. Testing this solution, seems it's working :-)

Comment: Depending on the number of users that might not help. But it is indeed a possibility when you do not use a different filter. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Solution for PHP < 5.4 is (tested ant it working):

```
$alph = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e',
        'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k',
        'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's',
        't', 'u', 'y', 'v', 'w', 'z');

    foreach ($alph as $letter){

    $sr = ldap_search($ldap, $dn, '(&(telephoneNumber=*)(sAMAccountName=' . $letter . '*))', array('cn','telephoneNumber','sAMAccountName'), null, 0, 0);

    $users = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $sr);
       foreach ($users as $user) {
        echo $user['sAMAccountName']['0']."<br/>";
        }
     }
```

Also you add numbers filter on e.g. telephoneNumber, it depends on how much records you have. If you have much more records you can try using more loops filtering by first and seconds letters like `sAMAccountName=' .$letter.$letter2.'*`